# Xamarin gives error for GetLayoutInflater. Doesn't read it. How can I fix this?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently using Xamarin.Android to create an activity that will browse files.

In the example that Xamarin provides, they use GetLayoutInflater as part of their FileListAdapter.cs.  For some reason, Xamarin is not registering the GetLayoutInflater.  What can I do?  It can't be code because I'm just copying from the sample.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using System.IO;

namespace RefrigerantID.Droid
{
    public class FileListAdapter : ArrayAdapter<FileSystemInfo>
    {
        private readonly Context _context;

        public FileListAdapter(Context context, IList<FileSystemInfo> fsi)
            : base(context, Resource.Layout.file_picker_list_item, Android.Resource.Id.Text1, fsi)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        ///   We provide this method to get around some of the
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="directoryContents"> </param>
        public void AddDirectoryContents(IEnumerable<FileSystemInfo> directoryContents)
        {
            Clear();
            // Notify the _adapter that things have changed or that there is nothing 
            // to display.
            if (directoryContents.Any())
            {
if __ANDROID_11__
                // .AddAll was only introduced in API level 11 (Android 3.0). 
                // If the "Minimum Android to Target" is set to Android 3.0 or 
                // higher, then this code will be used.
                AddAll(directoryContents.ToArray());
#else
                // This is the code to use if the "Minimum Android to Target" is
                // set to a pre-Android 3.0 API (i.e. Android 2.3.3 or lower).
                lock (this)
                    foreach (var fsi in directoryContents)
                    {
                        Add(fsi);
                    }
endif

                NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                NotifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var fileSystemEntry = GetItem(position);

            FileListRowViewHolder viewHolder;
            View row;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                row = _context.GetLayoutInflater().Inflate(Resource.Layout.file_picker_list_item, parent, false);
                viewHolder = new FileListRowViewHolder(row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.file_picker_text), row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.file_picker_image));
                row.Tag = viewHolder;
            }
            else
            {
                row = convertView;
                viewHolder = (FileListRowViewHolder)row.Tag;
            }
            viewHolder.Update(fileSystemEntry.Name, fileSystemEntry.IsDirectory() ? Resource.Drawable.folder : Resource.Drawable.file);

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

[Using Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7c0b.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naHD1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your `Context` is wrong.

The method `GetLayoutInflater` exists on a `FragmentActivity`, while `Activity` contains a property for getting the `LayoutInflater`.

Re: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/fragment/create_a_fragment/

Comment: Could you guide me on what to change?  It it because it's not "public class MyFragment : Fragment
{
}"

Comment: @neutJor ***If*** you are using Xamarin's example verbatim, then change your `Activity` to a `FragmentActivity`....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you pass the context to the constructor then to inflate the item layout

```
_context.GetLayoutInflater().Inflate(Resource.Layout.file_picker_list_item, parent, false);
```

You don't need to do that way.
Here is normally I do.

1. Access to context from parameter `parent`.
2. Use `LayoutInflater.FromContext(parent.Context)`

Hope it will help.